# dllimport : c code affect a struct passed by reference (c#)

Tags: c#, c, interop, dllimport

I've got a c dll that contains an exposed function, that takes three parameters :

```
int ParseInput(char* opt_path, char* input, SENNA_RESULT_ARRAY* result);
```

I want to call this from C#, which actually works. The problem is that the result struct is not affected.
Here is the structure defined in c code :

```
    typedef struct RESULT_
{
    char* word;
    int pos_start;
    int pos_end;
    char* pos;
    char* chk;
    char* ner;
    char* psg;

} RESULT;

typedef struct RESULT_ARRAY_
{
    int size;
    RESULT* Results;    
} RESULT_ARRAY;
```

and my c# code :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SENNA_RESULT
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string word;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        public int pos_start;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        public int pos_end;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pos;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string chk;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string ner;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string psg;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SENNA_RESULT_ARRAY
    {
        public SENNA_RESULT[] Results;     
        public int size;
    }

    [DllImport("Senna-32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    static extern int Parse(string msg, string stream, ref SENNA_RESULT_ARRAY results);

Parse(@"path", "sentence", ref result_array)
```

I've tried many things, like : 
1-use classes instead of struct without ref keyword
2-use a pointer instead of passing a struct

Each time i got a different error like
array is not of the specified type
low level error( corrupted heap)

even if i don't specify the array in the first struct, the size member has not the correct value (the C code prints the value in the console)

Any advice ?

Thanks

Comment: I can't speak with certainty, but I believe the correct syntax is `out SENNA_RESULT_ARRAY results`.

Comment: The order of members is different, `size` is the first element in the C result array struct and the last in the C# result array struct. Aren't the orders supposed to be equal?

Comment: This function is almost impossible to use correctly from a C program, it doesn't get better when you do it from C#.  There's a severe memory management problem, the array and all those strings need to be released again.  That requires the caller to use the same memory allocator as the callee, never the case from C#, rarely the case from C.

Comment: Klas you're right, but it's not the problem, i tried with the sequential order with the members in the same order but nothing changed. The sequence order here comes from a test i did with the Explicit and fieldoffset attributes.

Comment: Michael, i tried this at the begining, i'll try it again because i made few changes in c code.

Comment: Hans, i'm not sure to understand what your saying

Answer (score 0):

Consider using code below.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SENNA_RESULT
{
    public IntPtr word;
    public int pos_start;
    public int pos_end;
    public IntPtr pos;
    public IntPtr chk;
    public IntPtr ner;
    public IntPtr psg;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SENNA_RESULT_ARRAY
{
    public IntPtr Results;     
    public int size;
}

[DllImport("Senna-32.dll")]
static extern int Parse(string msg, string stream, out SENNA_RESULT_ARRAY results);
```

Here is usage example

```
        SENNA_RESULT_ARRAY array = new SENNA_RESULT_ARRAY();
        int result = Parse("path", "sentence", out array);
        if (result == SUCCESS && array.Results != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < array.size; index++)
            {
                IntPtr offset = (IntPtr)((int)array.Results + index * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SENNA_RESULT)));
                SENNA_RESULT senna = (SENNA_RESULT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(offset, typeof(SENNA_RESULT));
            }
        }
```

I hope that you understand that it is just idea. Make sure that code is working properly and then improve it to make it more comfotable to use. I talking about replacing `IntPtr` with `string`.